# control not reaching to selector

Tags: iphone

I have put a button over a toolbar.But when i press that button,my selector is not called and application crashes giving following error

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[ChatViewController changeButtonImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x119570'

here is my code..

```
UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,0,310,44)];
UIBarButtonItem *changeImagebtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize
                                                                                     target:self
                                                                                     action:@selector(changeButtonImage)];




    UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                              target:nil
                                                                              action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *textField = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:peerName];

    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textField,flexItem,flexItem,changeImagebtn,nil];
    [toolBar setItems:items animated:NO];
[self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```

My action block is ----

```
-(void)changeButtonImage:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *pic=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pick=pic;
    pick.delegate=self;

    pick.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:pick animated:YES];
}
```

where am i wrong?Please suggest me...

Comment: Your method Definition takes id type argument but when you call the method you don't give any argument!And also check you must declare the method in your .h file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
action:@selector(changeButtonImage)
```

it must be:

```
action:@selector(changeButtonImage:)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have said that instead of:

```
-(void)changeButtonImage:(id)sender {}
```

You would use:

```
-(void)changeButtonImage {}
```

That works perfectly fine for me in my apps and you're not using the sender in your method code anyway.

**EDIT :** of course remember that if you were going to do this then also amend your definition in the header file.